# Confusing results- 3M lead test kit

Tags: testing, lead

Besides the obvious orange color,  does it also look like there's a pinkish hue to you? I'm confused about these vinyl mini blind results.

The parts that aren't obviously orange, do they look pinkish to you? Does this indicate lead?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Consider [taking the tour].  What are you checking exactly?  Are you checking paint acquired elsewhere and using these vinyl blinds as a blotter? Or are you testing for lead paint *on the vinyl blinds*?   Are the blinds newer than 1978?

Comment: They're not painted, they're vinyl mini blinds which I recently learned before 1996 some overseas manufacturers added lead as a stabilizer ... they're hanging in an old house we just bought and wanted to check, as I busted my baby playing with them. Have called 3M they weren't very helpful, so was hoping there might be an expert out there or someone with experience.

Comment: The dribble looking one was just that, a dribble but the oval shaped one was were I tested on the blind

Comment: I agree that's worrisome and worth further investigation. Can you look up in the top area above the blinds, for any maker's marks?  That's where the mechanism, any labeling, and lots of dust will be.

Comment: To clarify, lead was added to the vinyl.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered. They should not have done that. Hope somebody really enjoyed the latté they bought with the savings.

Comment: I'll take a look at the top area thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Is anyone in your family going to eat the mini blinds or put on their mouth? People get way over worried about lead and asbestos. Lead was a great additive to paint, the problem comes in when the paint chips off and a child comes along and puts it in their mouth and eats it. Mini blinds in my area are as cheap as $4.99 per window. Just replace the blinds if you are that worried.

Comment: Hand to mouth causes ingestion also, which is what my baby did after touching them, thus my concern. ( we were told at the pediatrician that metal mini blinds were the concern, we knew nothing of vinyl) She also recently had a lead paint chip in her mouth after mouthing an old trunk at an air bnb we stayed at and tested positive for lead in her blood so as you can imagine my worry is valid.

Comment: Just asking if this looks like a positive result is all. Would appreciate feedback on that anybody with experience- thanks!

Comment: From* anybody.  ** NB I have talked to 3M , weren't very helpful, which is why I'm here.

Comment: what does it mean that she "tested positive for lead in her blood"? Of course there's lead in blood, it's everywhere after all. Did she have an unexpected amount, or just a detectable amount?

Comment: Shes 1 and no she isn't meant to have the amount of lead in her blood that she did.

Comment: Can I only get comments regarding the photo PLEASE?

Comment: We are trying to get to you is that if it was just detectable, then that is normal. Lead is in the air we breath, the meat we eat, seafood, fruits and vegetables so something just detectable is normal. If it was a high amount, that is cause for concern.

Comment: Right, the amount in her blood was higher than it should be for her age.

Answer (score 1):

On the lead based paint I have tested the results were within 1 minute red not orange. I have seen another post on this site that a test turned orange days later, the belief is he chemicals oxidized and are no longer active. 
To me that looks like a negative result. 
I have found more lead in older homes drinking water.

Prior to the requirement to use non lead solder, many plumbing fixtures had lead in them (until 1986)  copper pipes pre 80’s were sweated with tin/lead solder. I don’t remember the year lead solder was banned but looked up lead free plumbing by 1988, so if your child has higher than background levels you should be looking at your water as this is the main contributing factor in most areas. Especially older homes.

Comment: Thank you so much for you insight Ed!